# Programmatic Report, Conditional Formatting - Right Approach?

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2010

Fairly new to VBA, used to working in PHP, javascript, other web tech stuff.

I'm building a database in Access.  Because of the way I've structured the tables, the report I have to generate is being created programmatically.  I couldn't figure out how to do it any other way since the SQL statement relies on an input from a combo box (you'll see in the code below).

The problem I have run in to is trying to conditionally format the report being created programmatically.  It's an aircraft maintenance planning database, and I want to create a report that will color code when scheduled inspections are coming due.  So if an inspection is 50 hours away, that inspection will show up in orange, things that are overdue will show up as red.  But I can't figure out how to do this with a recordset.

I have tried converting the recordset into a multidimensional array and iterating through the array to create the controls and apply conditional formatting.  But for some reason I ended up with that pesky "Enter parameter value" dialogue box for every record produced and threw in the towel on that approach.

So my question is how is this possible?  And my second question is am I approaching the structure of my tables and reports the right way?  From my php experience, I would apply my conditional formatting logic to the returned array, but I have full control over the array unlike the recordset in Access.  Or should I be applying the logic within the recordset before generating the report?  Or should I be applying the logic to the SQL and reformat my queries?

Whichever way makes sense, at the end of the day I want to be able to create the report with conditional formatting based on how close the current data is to the benchmark data.

Here is the code for creating the report:

```
Private Sub Command5_Click()

Dim strSQL As String
Dim aircraft As String
Dim Title As String 'holds title of report


aircraft = [Forms]![DeviationSelectionForm]![cmbAircraft]

Dim status As Integer

status = [Forms]![DeviationSelectionForm]![opt_status]

Title = "Deviations and SPFPs - AC CH12" & aircraft

If status = 1 Then
    strSQL = "SELECT Deviations.Deviation, Deviations.Link, Deviations.Rev, Deviations.Title, Deviations.Issued, Deviations.ExpiryDate, Deviations.ExpiryHours, Deviations.ExpOther FROM Deviations WHERE Deviations.[" & [Forms]![DeviationSelectionForm]![cmbAircraft] & "]=True AND Deviations.Active=True ORDER BY Deviations.Deviation DESC;"
    Title = Title & " - Active"
ElseIf status = 2 Then
    strSQL = "SELECT Deviations.Deviation, Deviations.Link, Deviations.Rev, Deviations.Title, Deviations.Issued, Deviations.ExpiryDate, Deviations.ExpiryHours, Deviations.ExpOther FROM Deviations WHERE Deviations.[" & [Forms]![DeviationSelectionForm]![cmbAircraft] & "]=True AND Deviations.Active=False ORDER BY Deviations.Deviation DESC;"
    Title = Title & " - Inactive"
ElseIf status = 3 Then
    strSQL = "SELECT Deviations.Deviation, Deviations.Link, Deviations.Rev, Deviations.Title, Deviations.Issued, Deviations.ExpiryDate, Deviations.ExpiryHours, Deviations.ExpOther FROM Deviations WHERE Deviations.[" & [Forms]![DeviationSelectionForm]![cmbAircraft] & "]=True ORDER BY Deviations.Deviation DESC;"
    Title = Title & " - All"
End If


Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim txtNew As Access.TextBox ' textbox control
Dim lblNew As Access.Label ' label control
Dim rpt As Report ' hold report object
Dim lngTop As Long ' holds top value of control position
Dim lngLeft As Long ' holds left value of controls position


lngLeft = 0
lngTop = 400

'Create the report

Set rpt = CreateReport

' set properties of the report

With rpt
    .Width = 8500
    .RecordSource = strSQL
    .Caption = Title
End With

rpt.Section("Detail").Height = 2000

' Open SQL query as a recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)


' Create label title
Set lblNew = CreateReportControl(rpt.Name, acLabel, acPageHeader, , Title, 0, 0)

With lblNew
    .FontBold = True
    .FontSize = 16


End With

    lblNew.SizeToFit

' Create corresponding label and text box controls for each field.

For Each fld In rs.Fields


    'Create new text box control and size to fit data.

       Set txtNew = CreateReportControl(rpt.Name, acTextBox, acDetail, , fld.Name, lngLeft + 1500, lngTop)

       txtNew.Width = 8000
       txtNew.TextAlign = 1
       txtNew.BorderStyle = 0

       'Create new label control and size to fit data.
       Set lblNew = CreateReportControl(rpt.Name, acLabel, acDetail, txtNew.Name, fld.Name, lngLeft, lngTop, 1400, txtNew.Height)
       lblNew.SizeToFit

     'Increment top value for next control
     lngTop = lngTop + txtNew.Height + 25

Next


' Create datestamp in Footer
Set lblNew = CreateReportControl(rpt.Name, acLabel, acPageFooter, , Now(), 0, 0)

' Create page numbering on footer
Set txtNew = CreateReportControl(rpt.Name, acTextBox, acPageFooter, , "='Page ' & [Page] & ' of ' & [Pages]", rpt.Width - 1000, 0)

txtNew.SizeToFit

' Open new report
DoCmd.OpenReport rpt.Name, acViewReport
DoCmd.MoveSize 0, 50, 12000, 14000



'reset all objects

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set rpt = Nothing
Set db = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you're doing this with a form to open the report. And the ad-hoc report creation is way over what you need. At least from what you've shown all you need is possibly one or two unbound label/text controls that the get theair caption/value from a form field, and then open the report with a filter.

Comment: I think I became hamstrung early on when I found I had difficulty creating a query with part of it derived from a combo box.  I believe you are right and I have over complicated my approach from the outset.